# Hosting Wordpress on a different domain hosting package

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting

I have a few domains that are hosted with the same hosting company.

I want to have all the WordPress websites files to be stored on one domain FTP server, inside their own directories.

I also want the databases to be stored on the same domain.

Is there a way to accomplish this? 
And if yes, how can I do it?

Sorry if this may be a bit confusing, as I never have done this or heard of it before.

Comment: Do you have separate hosting account (or FTP account) for each of the WordPress sites?

Comment: Hi, they are all under the same account profile, through  Xneelo

Comment: I only have a hosting package for the 1 domain, the other domains I just bought, with no hosting package

Comment: In this case you already have all of them under the same hosting. And to make it clear: domain is the name of the site, like `example.com`. Hosting is the server place where you are storing your site's files and database. Hosting provider is the company that is providing the hosting for your sites. So the questions is are the sites on the same hosting (storage)? Also I'm not sure if you are not looking for WordPress [multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) solution.

Comment: Hi Ale, Sorry for that miss communication from my side. They are not under the same hosting packaged, just under the same account.

Comment: Thanks. One final question. Do you have access to cPanel as administrative panel of your hosting account (the one where you want to move everything). I'm asking as I can give you hints only for cPanel.